# Why does substring-before function in XSLT is returning blank?

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am trying to return the text value before the delimiter with xslt function and is returning blank.

Following is the sample xml

```
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:EmployeeID>123</wd:EmployeeID>
<wd:FirstName>Robert</wd:FirstName>
<wd:LastName>Henry</wd:LastName>
<wd:Email>robert.henry@y.com</wd:Email>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

I did try the following function and is returning blank.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before('wd:Email','@')"/>
```

Also tried this well and is returning blank.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before('wd:Email/text()','@')"/>
```

I was expecting something as below

```
Robert.henry
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before('wd:Email','@')"/>
```

looks at the literal **string** `"wd:Email"` and looks for the `"@"` character in it. It can't find any, so the result is an empty string.

If you want the expression to look at the string-value of the `wd:Email` **element**, you need to remove the quotes around the first argument:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(wd:Email, '@')"/>
```

Then you will get the expected result - provided that you are in the right context and that you have declared the correct namespace for the `wd` prefix (note that the example input you show does not bind the prefix to a namespace, and therefore is not a well-formed XML and all it will produce is an error).